# Unable to install OS X, cmd+R opening internet recovery instead of usual recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, recovery-hd, internet-recovery

I'm trying to clean install OS X El Capitan on a MacBook Pro (early 2015).

After erasing my disk I started the installation of OS X. After accepting the license agreement I was asked to choose a target drive. I hesitated a little bit and wanted to cross-check if I have created the partitions correctly so I canceled the installation. There were no options to go back to Disk Utility so I restarted my machine.

Now when I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, it always leads me to internet recovery. The only thing I saw was a spinning globe and I was asked to choose a Wi-Fi connection. I connected to my Wi-Fi network and still only saw a spinning globe. After waiting for a long time it has shown the error **apple.com/support 2002f**

How can I access the normal recovery mode and install OS X?

Comment: `2002f` usually indicates a network connectivity issue (most likely your MBP can't connect to the WiFi), so it could just be a mistyped password. Doesn't get you out of internet recovery but may allow you to proceed nevertheless.

Comment: @patrix, I tried change to other wifi connection too. Im sure there is no problem in psw. Also there is a wifi icon that gives me impressions that it is connected successfully

Comment: Please don't add answers/solutions to the question, post it as an answer instead below.

Comment: BEWARE of internet recovery mode if you have an older Mac. it does not work on many. my 2011 MacBook Pro needed a firmware update (available on apple recovery info page) before I proceeded to erase OS X and enter internet recovery mode. (I did this as my computer was very glitchy after a failed/attempted download of high Sierra) I was following instructions from Mac OS X daily but they did not mention this and now it is too late and my computer is wiped with no option to get an OS X back on it. Apple senior experts have tried for days and no luck.

Comment: it does not recognise any external hard drives with OS X on them, so no option to boot from a startup disk option either. one morning a working computer the next dead

Comment: Recently had the same issue while attempting to clean install macOS mojave 10.14.1. The error code was exactly -2002F (for internet recovery) and -2002D (for built in diagnostics tool) and after a number of messages exchanged with Apple support on Twitter it turned out that my router needed a reboot. I had also changed the primary and secondary DNS servers but I don't think this had to do anything with the problem honestly. So after rebooting the internet recovery started functioning normally. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a workaround for this problem. It seems somehow my system hates my Wi-Fi connection (may be due to some encryptions related to Wi-Fi). When I went to my friend's place and connected to Wi-Fi, I was able to proceed with Internet Recovery. After waiting 5 minutes, I landed on a page similar to normal recovery mode and then I was able to install OS X normally (Yosemite was installed in this case).

If this doesn't work, I would have create a bootable installer for OS X as suggested by David's and bmike's answer

Comment: In terms of a sequence for changing the network (e.g., if for some reason your machine needs 2.4G rather than 5G), restart and hold OPT+SHIFT+CMD+R. Select the network, enter the password, then press CMD+R to start Internet Recovery.

Answer (score 5):

Your model Mac was shipped with Yosemite (OS X 10.10) installed. The tags you placed on the question suggest you have upgraded to El Capitan (OS X 10.11). There is the possibility you could have erased the Recovery partition by using the Disk Utility if you had Yosemite installed. Evidently, this would be much harder (or perhaps impossible) to do if El Capitan was installed. Also, I do not know if you were using Core Storage and if so, how this would effect the ability to erase the Recovery partition.

Evidentially, you can now only boot using OS X Internet Recovery. You can use Internet Recovery to install the version of OS X that came with your machine. From this, you can go to the App Store and download and install newer versions of OS X.

An alternative would be to use another Mac to download OS X. You can then transfer the download to a USB drive. You then use the USB drive to install OS X on your Mac. The instructions are given the Apple web site: [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

Comment: That's probably not true: at least in a VM you won't be able to "shoot the horse under your butt" (I don't know if this figure of speech exists in english - a similar one does in german). You can't erase the Recovery HD (or the complete disk containing it) with Disk Utility!

Comment: @klanomath: I revised my answer. Even though I can test the deletion of the recovery partition using a sparse disk image, I do not know if erasing the OS X partition while booted from the recovery partition would yield the same results. (I just not currently setup in a way that I can test this)

Comment: You can erase (format) the main system **volume** but you will get the following error trying to erase (partition) the whole disk (containing the main OS X volume & the Recovery HD the Mac is booted to): "Trying to unmount the disk... Impossible to unmount the disk... Action failed!"

Comment: The `Disk Utility` in any of the 2 recovery modes permit to completely erase the internal disk, including the hidden recovery partition. I did this on purpose on seriously damaged disk and I hopefully I had this level of repair accessible.

Comment: @danielAzuelos (non-Internet) Recovery HD's El Cap Disk Utility erases itself? I doubt that on a properly working disk!

Comment: I admit the behavior I have been referring to occurs when using a Yosemite recovery partition. After testing using an El Capitan recovery partition, I see different results. Here the recovery partition is unaffected  by changes to the OS X partition. I have no idea which version of OS X someone_ smiley is using.

Comment: @DavidAnderson The tags suggest ElCap.

Comment: I'm using El Capitan, sorry for not making it clear enough

Comment: Thank you for your helps, Create a bootable installer would be one of good work around to this problem. but i have get around this problem now. Please see update to the question for details.

Answer (score 5):

The Recovery Partition on the system disk corresponds to the version of the macOS installed. Since you aborted installation of macOS just after partitioning (thus erasing all partitions, including Recovery) the only option for your Mac was a fallback to Internet Recovery.

However, according to [HT204904](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204904) there are actually several key combinations for (Internet) Recovery giving you a choice of macOS version you want to install:

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - Install the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac, without upgrading to a later version. (currently that being macOS 10.13 High Sierra)

<kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - Upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac. (currently that being macOS 10.13 High Sierra)

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - Install the macOS that came with your Mac, or the version closest to it that is still available. (for your computer that is macOS 10.10 Yosemite - source: [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.7-13-early-2015-retina-display-specs.html))

Answer (score 3):

Disconnect from the network if you care and then hold the option key when you reboot.

If you have a viable standard recovery HD it will be shown. From there you can attempt to repartition or download an installer.

- Check your time, if it’s off more than three minutes, TLS and SSL will sporadically fail.
- Then [check DNS](https://talesofatech.com/2017/03/rule-1-its-always-dns/), if your Mac can’t find Apple’s servers, this
  won’t work.

Another option is to use another bootable OS to run the repair / install. Holding option will let you select those OS once they are connected.

Once you're booted - the steps are the same as recovering from Internet Recovery: [Erased Macintosh HD and installing OS X Lion again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97021/erased-macintosh-hd-and-installing-lion-osx-again)

Comment: I have found work around to the problem. Your method would work too as last resort. Please see update to questions for detail. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not to take anything away from anyone here... I had hit the wall on this error too. Just could not get the Internet recovery mode to connect to Apple. I found an article that said to edit DNS to 8.8.8.8. I noticed my router had an option for secondary DNS, put in 8.8.8.8 and internet recovery connected first attempt.
https://westerntechies.com/apple-macbook-error-2002f/
Hope it helps someone else. I was worried my 16yo bricked a $4,000 mac book pro!

Comment: Never forget rule 1 - it’s always DNS. https://talesofatech.com/2017/03/rule-1-its-always-dns/

Comment: I faced the same issue today, and I'm very much interested about what magic Apple wants to successfully boot over the Internet. I'm running my own bind9 in my LAN and so far I only have issues when I propagate that to DHCP clients needing recovery. When propagating Cloudflare, or Google DNS, I can successfully boot over the net.

Answer (score 1):

There is another nice way to avoid the DNS time sync problem and the local internet problem with your at home router.

- Power off
- Tether to a Hotspot on a mobile device with a data plan
- Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> and then Power On
- You will be prompted with a wifi selection menu, select your Mobile Hotspot from the list
- Power Off.  At this point the recovery booter has cached your hotspot as its last internet connection
- Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and then Power On
- Boot loader will now start your internet recovery tethering off your mobile data plan which avoids the DNS and time sync issues.

On LTE device it took about 6 minutes to move past the internet recovery then proceeded to be able to install the OS again

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct date and time via terminal using external ntp server. This is why connection fails (SSL).

Comment: This may work, but the OP needs to know how to get to Terminal to make the change.